What challenge did Jesus put before the rich young man in Mtt19?
We see in Mtt 19:16-21 ,the rendezvous of  Jesus and the Rich Young Man :

And, behold, one came and said unto him, Good Master, what good thing shall I do, that I may have eternal life? And he said unto him, Why callest thou me good? there is none good but one, that is, God: but if thou wilt enter into life, keep the commandments........20 The young man saith unto him, All these things have I kept from my youth up: what lack I yet? 21 Jesus said unto him, If thou wilt be perfect, go and sell that thou hast, and give to the poor, and thou shalt have treasure in heaven: and come and follow me.

Note the usage ' perfect'in Verse 21. Jesus is putting a challenge which the young man does not accept.           Now, the usage 'perfect' is peculiar to English. It has no Degree of Comparison as in 'good-better-best'.  Many oriental languages do not have  have an original one-word counterpart for the term. Some of them have a roughly fair translation to imply completeness. We may never know the  Aramaic word that Jesus used and its implications. It is quite likely that Jesus  used the word for completeness or wholeness, akin to what he said of the Redemptive Passion on the Cross ( Jn 19:30). My question is : What exactly was the challenge Jesus had put before the rich  young man in Mtt:19 ?

After rereading, I think I've understood now, scratch my first comment.

Thanks, user111403. Jesus first tells him the simplest way to salvation that is observance of Commandments in the form of Good Deeds. Next level that is perfection would mean discarding of all material wealth to follow Jesus. The man was ready to go for the base level and not the higher one . Verses 22 to 24 suggest that he lost both, simply because he chose to remain rich. But what if he followed Jesus' challenge ? Would he experience heaven even before he died ? Hence my question.

Up-voted +1.  But there is no 'challenge'. Everything is freely offered.

There is no 'challenge'.

Jesus offers the man 'treasure in heaven'. This treasure must be vast in value, being heavenly, and also must be a righteous thing to possess, if it is 'in' heaven.
This is a truly staggering offer. Why, on earth, would anyone not desire it and drop everything to obtain it ?
Jesus asks for no works, no effort, no ability, no competence, no persistence - nothing. Just give what you have to the poor. And this immense treasure will be yours.
Whyever not do it ? What sane man would refuse ?
And then ?
Come, follow me.
. . . . . . . . What ?
Follow this One ? This 'Good Master' ?
The opportunity of a lifetime.
Breathtaking.
To learn of . . .  Him ! To be led, to be governed, to be instructed.
Staggering.
That the man is crestfallen and gives no response reveals volumes about himself, his true spiritual condition and his real motives in life.
And there he stands, exposed.
Not 'challenged'.
He had nothing to do.
All was freely offered.
He just had to release.
And that, he could not do.
So what of the tenth commandment ? Exodus 20:17.
If he gave it all away, he admits, by not doing so, that he would long, yearn and crave - to have it back again.
He can't let it go.
That is what is revealed by the wisdom of Jesus, and his perception into the soul of one who came to him, desiring to know what he might do to gain eternal life.
Eternal life is not a matter of doing anything.
It is a matter of believing on the One who has already done all to obtain it. John 3:16. 1 John 5:13. Romans 6:23. John 4:14.
And believing means yielding all to the One who is believed on.
Everything.
He that forsaketh not all that he hath - cannot be my disciple, Luke 14:33.
It is all or it is nothing.
It is all . . .   Him.
It is being crucified with Him, being risen with Him, being ascended with Him and being seated in the heavenlies in Him. Ephesians 2:6.
But there is nothing for the flesh to do.
Nothing to boast in.
Nothing to covet.
Come, follow me.

But God forbid that I should glory, save in the cross of our Lord Jesus Christ, by whom the world is crucified unto me, and I unto the world. [Galatians 6:14 KJV]


Thanks, Nigel J, for the scholarly inputs. St Mother Theresa famously said : "Give  until you are hurt ! "  But the 'poor ' rich young man told to give till he became Zero.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Yes, indeed. Forsake all and follow Him. The only thing to do with one's existence.

+1, but... "Jesus asks for no works" Giving everything you own to the poor is a work. And yes, in exchange for treasure in heaven, you'd be foolish not to make the trade - but you have to believe in the treasure in heaven to do it. You have to believe that the one making the promise can and will carry through. The direction from Jesus is a test of his faith (which is why this text isn't teaching salvation by works). So there is in some sense a challenge here, and it's the same one Jesus presents to his disciples: "Who do you believe that I am?"

@user111403 I disagree but feel free to answer the question as you see fit.

Care to expand on what exactly you disagree with? What is giving all your possessions to the poor, if not a work?

@user111403 It is the Lord pointing directly at the heart of unbelief in a man.  He is not advocating a 'work' but exposing the sinful heart.  If this man's primary hang-up was pride Jesus would have pointed toward humility.  The answer to "Who you you say that I am?" is not a work either...at least not a human work.  Jesus' response to Peter?  Flesh and blood does not give this revelation:  It is a work of God.  Therein is Peter blessed.  Not by work but believing and confessing Divine revelation.  Give to the poor, sure, but don't pat yourself on the head for it.

@MikeBorden Exactly! I don't really see this as a disagreement? I just don't see saying "Jesus asks for no works", when He does, very specifically ask for a work. Which is why I think it's important to make the point why - the work He asks for is to demonstrate the man's belief, or lack thereof, and not itself a means to salvation. Or as you put it, "pointing directly at the heart of unbelief in a man".

@user111403 Just chipping in to agree that helping the poor in a material way certainly is work (e.g. helping them rebuild shelter after a tornado, or bury their dead after a flood.) But all such good work is not in exchange for God-given salvation. After all, atheists may do exactly the same good work but disbelieve God even exists. They may even boast their motives are purer than those hoping to merit God's favour. But those saved by the grace of God WILL do good works, BECAUSE they are now saved and released to show the love of Christ!

@Anne Of course! I did write in so many words that "this text isn't teaching salvation by works" and that this is about belief - he'd have to believe in Jesus to do the work. To be honest, even after re-reading I still don't see why this isn't clear, but evidently it isn't...

@Anne They that will be rich pierce themselves through with many sorrows. It is a release and a relief to be rid of the burden. 'Sell' and give' is not "work". It is a mercy for Jesus to say to the man - sell and give. 'My yoke is easy and my burden is light' can be said of no religion on earth other than the true following of the Son of God.

@user111403  Clarity in your comments was lost when you said, "yes, in exchange for treasure in heaven, you'd be foolish not to make the trade -" That implies that we are to do something first, and then we will be rewarded with something much better on offer. But Jesus said that there's no reward for doing what we ought to do. See Luke 17:7-9. We ought to serve the Lord only, forsaking Mammon, which is not a work.

@Anne I see, thanks for pointing that out. Yes, it was a bit unclear, I suppose it would be better to say "you'd be foolish to value temporary earthly wealth over heavenly treasure".

If there is a challenge (and I'm not sure challenge is the right word) it is here:  "Why callest thou me good? there is none good but one, that is, God".
Who do you say that I am?

The young man saith unto him, All these things have I kept from my youth up: what lack I yet?

If I am Good (God) then why are you bringing your failed self righteousness before me, your works, as though they have merit?  If your reliance is upon these things then your lack is absolute.
If I am merely a good human teacher then I will point you to the Law and exhort you to labor there to the point of unreachable perfection.
Who do you say that I am?

But when the young man heard that saying, he went away sorrowful: for he had great possessions.

Making no choice is, in itself, a choice which brings great sorrow.

Why are you adding out of context language “who do you say I am” this is not the direction Jesus was going in with respect to the young man? As a larger study in a broader context but this question is about this passage.

@NihilSineDeo "Why callest thou me good?" isn't much different than "Who do you say that I am?".  Only God is good and you're calling me good.. what exactly are you trying to say?

I’m saying you’re diverting the point of the event if you are focusing on this being proof of Jesus’ divinity, Jesus was making the point that no human qualifies as good, which would nullify the young man’s attempts of reaching a state of righteousness via works. Jesus out the gate is demolishing his works based effort to gain eternal life.

@NihilSineDeo  I'm not denying that is also a point that Jesus is making.  I'm pretty sure the Lord of Glory can make two points at the same time without breaking a sweat :)

yes God can Hit two birds with one stone but it’s not from this passage that you extract this claim. I can confidently state this because Jesus never makes reference back to his divinity at all throughout this whole passage. That’s why it’s a distraction to point to a minor side point and ignore the purpose of the historical account

@NihilSineDeo Well, unless I've been very unclear in my answer, I've derived the point you perceive from the point I perceive.  Thus, I hold your point as true and derivative and you hold somewhat the opposite; major point/minor point.  Maybe the difference has more to do with us than with the passage itself?

Definitely has everything to do with you @Mike I agree

I happen to be conducting an in depth study of Mark at the moment and would offer this by comparing Matthew's account to Mark's. It is clearly the same episode, but Mark's closing is different:
Mark 10

21 Jesus, looking at him, loved him and said to him, “You are lacking
in one thing. Go, sell what you have, and give to the poor and you
will have treasure in heaven; then come, follow me.” 22 At that
statement his face fell, and he went away sad, for he had many
possessions.

The challenge in both narratives is to forsake one's worldly goods and attain 'treasure in heaven' by accepting discipleship. I suggest that the OP may be looking at the wrong concept here (achieving perfection rather than discipleship). Both Mark's version and Matthew's show Jesus to be telling the man to give up all his earthly goods and "come and follow me." That is the challenge. Achieving perfection - by any definition - comes later, after the man has responded to the challenge to divest himself of his wealth and has accepted the invitation to discipleship.

Thanks, Dan Fefferman. I personally am not in favour of the usage perfection . Jesus minced no words in saying that only God is Good. Perfection takes place above the grading good . Could a human being be perfect even if he discarded everything and followed Jesus? My feeling is that Jesus meant completeness

@KadalikattJosephSibichan I too favor completeness to perfection. It's fascinating to me that Mark quotes Jesus as saying "you lack one thing." And that thing is that the young man must divest himself of his possessions and, on that foundation, come and follow Jesus. This is why I think the challenge is discipleship first, completeness/perfection after that. In many cases it may not be possessions that keep one from discipleship, but whatever keeps us from devoting our whole heart.

The point of the passage and the discussion with the rich young ruler was to set the stage for the new covenant modality.
In the old covenant you could live like the devil but so long as you had the finances to offer sacrifices you would always be covered on the technicality of the law.
Jesus was trying to point out to the young man that he was not in alignment with the old covenant law and that the young ruler had broken these laws but the young ruler with the old covenant thinking knowing he could afford the sacrifices felt that he had kept all those laws.
We know that no one is justified under the law. Because it is faith that justifies. That’s why Jesus ups the ante and says if you want to be perfect. Why perfect? Because the young man was not perfect and because perfection is required for eternal life.
And Jesus gives the young man the solution, sell everything you have and come follow me, in other words live by faith and so being self reliant, stop trusting in your finances to atone for your sins, God is not a fool, God knows you are not trusting in God, but trusting in your flesh and your resources to get you into eternal life.

“When the disciples heard this, they were greatly astounded and said, “Then who can be saved?””
‭‭Matthew‬ ‭19‬:‭25‬ ‭

Why astonished? Because they were thinking like old covenant thinkers with sacrifices for sin and this young man was covered for life, he was practically guaranteed eternal life because he could afford to meet all the requirements of the law.
Jesus is pointing to the fact that it is faith that saves not works.

“But Jesus looked at them and said, “For mortals it is impossible, but for God all things are possible.””
‭‭Matthew‬ ‭19‬:‭26‬ ‭

We are saved by faith not by works.
“For by grace you have been saved through faith, and this is not your own doing; it is the gift of God—”
‭‭Ephesians‬ ‭2‬:‭8‬ ‭
And that was the problem for the Jews they were focused on works.

“but Israel, who did strive for the law of righteousness, did not attain that law. Why not? Because they did not strive for it on the basis of faith but as if it were based on works. They have stumbled over the stumbling stone,”
‭‭Romans‬ ‭9‬:‭31‬-‭32‬ ‭

Conclusión
What was Jesus’ challenge to the young man? Stop being self reliant, don’t rely on the flesh/carnality, don’t put stock in your works and your striving, trust me (Jesus) to take you to eternal life by faith.

Thanks, Nihil Sine Deo, for the hard-hitting answer. But you refer to the young man as a ruler . Only the subtitle of CSB says he was.

@Kadalikatt seeing it’s a synoptic gospel I took the liberty to cross reference Luke 18:18 which relates the same account from a different vantage point and it says he was a ruler.

Thanks, Nihil Sine Deo. Please carry on.

The initial challenge for the young man in Matthew 19 is one of understanding. Beginning with his first question, the man’s misconceptions and Jesus’ efforts to educate him are explored from a semantic and lexical perspective. Conceiving eternal life as a reward to be earned, the man asks Jesus what he can do to have eternal life.

“What good thing shall I do that I may have eternal life?” – NKJV

In his response, there is a notable difference in the verbs that Jesus uses. The changes in wording represent a subtle but significant reframing of the relationship between eternal life and God’s commandments. Rather than one of work and reward, Jesus presents eternal life as a goal/destination and the keeping of God’s commandments, the point of entry.

“If you want to enter into life, keep the commandments.”

“All these I have kept,” the man says in reply. “What do I still lack?” The word translated as “lack” is hustereó (ὑστερέω G5302), a verb that means “to come late, be behind, come short.” That the man has caught on to the idea of eternal life as an end/goal is reflected in his use of the word hustereó.
Although he has kept the commandments mentioned in vv. 18-19, the man acknowledges that he has yet to reach the goal. From a semantic standpoint, Jesus’ use of the word perfect/teleios (τέλειος G5046) – literally, “having reached its end” – dovetails nicely with the word hustereó. It also fits well within the conceptual framework that Jesus is trying to convey.
Note also the infinitive that Jesus uses in v. 21: “If you want to be perfect.” At the start of the discourse, the man considered eternal life as a reward to be earned. Here, Jesus redefines it as a state of being.

“If you want to be perfect, go, sell what you have and give to the
poor, and you will have treasure in heaven; and come, follow Me.”

The word teleios occurs 19x in the TR but only twice in the gospel of Matthew: Mt 19:21 and 5:48. To understand what “to be perfect” in Mt 19:21 entails, Jesus’ detailed description in Mt 5:44-48 is a good place to start.
Matthew 5:44-48

44 But I say to you, love your enemies, bless those who
curse you, do good to those who hate you, and pray for those who
spitefully use you and persecute you, 45 that you may be
sons of your Father in heaven; for He makes His sun rise on the evil
and on the good, and sends rain on the just and on the unjust.
46 For if you love those who love you, what reward have
you? Do not even the tax collectors do the same? 47 And if
you greet your brethren only, what do you do more than others? Do not
even the tax collectors do so? 48 Therefore you shall be
perfect, just as your Father in heaven is perfect.

Matthew 5:44-48 also accords with Jesus’ words in v. 17: "No one is good but One, that is, God.” For men, there is only one path “to be perfect,” to follow Jesus, but it requires that we let go of everything that might stand in our way. Ultimately, the challenge for the young man, as it is for many of us, is this: to live according to what he believes and has finally come to understand.
